# Vue2 PWA is not working on iOS 16.4 devices

Tags: ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

Our vue2 PWA is not working on iOS 16.4 devices. Only a white screen is shown. The app works in older ios versions and in chrome, firefox, etc.

Comment: Please provide something, or anything. How would anyone be able to help you?

Comment: We had the exact same problem (white screen + when "Web Content Restrictions" is active)
Apple released a new update today and it seems like they fixed it.

Comment: I am seeing this issue also using Vue3 PWA on IOS 16.5. After a period of time (maybe 24 hours) the app will not display fetch results. Static cached pages display fine (like about page). Thought it was a session problem but the session hasn't expired.

Comment: I am still having an issue with norifications not working on my react pwa

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same issue since upgrading to iOS 16.4.1 (from iOS 15 dot something).

It turns out the PWA works again after disabling *Web Content Restrictions* within *Content Restrictions* in *Screen Time* settings on my iOS device. I could reliably reproduce this on multiple devices.

It's not the first time that those content restrictions caused problems for me on something that should definitely not be affected by those filters.

Comment: This advice worked on my customer's iPhone, they were having white screen issues on my PWA, thank you :-)

Comment: This is a great clue - unfortunately in my case, I'm having the issue on multiple devices even without screen time enabled. These are corporate iPads, and I suspect equivalent MDM settings are causing the issue.

Comment: We are in same boat @Eric. Disabling Screen Time Web Content Restrictions fixed it for us (and allows us to easily reproduce the issue by enabling this and setting it to anything other than Unrestricted), however we have several big clients that use MDM to apply similar content filters that can't be removed. Interestingly, one of them reported that brand new devices out the box running 16.4 with the content filters applied using MDM seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue on iOS 16.4.1, iOS 16.5, and macOS Safari 16.5. I also thought it was the Service Worker at first. Removing it seemed to have fixed it, however after more testing I realized it wasn't working and still showing the blank screen.

I am using Ionic 5.X, so the following may not apply but still is a good tip...

While I never truly figured out the root issue, upgrading `@ionic-native/core`, `@ionic/vue`, and `@ionic/vue-router` to the newest minor 5.x versions fixed the issue for us. I recommend a minor update to your Ionic packages to see if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in iOS 16.4. For me the point of failure was event.respondWith. If you just return the fetch - even from cache it works fine. The problem with that is you lose offline capabilities. My solution (using injectManifest):

service-worker.js:

```
const assetObjectArr = self.__WB_MANIFEST;

function isIterable(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    return false;
  }
  return typeof obj[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}

const cacheName = 'MyCacheV1';

const assets = [];
if (isIterable(assetObjectArr)) {
  for (const asset of assetObjectArr) {
    assets.push(asset.url);
  }
}

let isIOS16 = true;
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }

  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'isIOS16') {
    isIOS16 = event.data.isIOS16;
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', (installEvent) => {
  // Delete old caches
  caches.delete(cacheName);

  // Add all assets to the cache
  installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
      cache.addAll(assets);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (isIOS16) {
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      // Cache hit - return response
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    });
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  }
});
```

Then on front end:

```
function checkForIOS16() {
  appVersion.value = navigator.appVersion;
  let isIOS16 =
    navigator.appVersion.includes('Version/16.4') &&
    /iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent);

  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
      type: 'isIOS16',
      isIOS16
    });
  });
}
```

This keeps offline capabilities for all non iOS iPhone 16.4 users.
Obviously this is just a work-around. If anyone has a better solution that would be great!

EDIT: This solution will work for about a day and then fail. PWA for iOS 16.4 does seem to be broken for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-ideal workaround, if you can't or don't want to disable web content restrictions.

Go to Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Experimental Features:  Then disable Service Workers.

This fixed the problem on two unrelated websites where I was facing the issue.

Comment: I think that would solve the problem, but it would break offline functionality

Comment: True, but just an option for those unable to disable certain web content restrictions

Answer (score 0):

We updated our devices to the latest 16.5 Beta Release 4 Release and so far in our testing it appears this may have resolved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I’m still having this problem with iOS 16.5 and iPadOS 16.5. I’m also able to reproduce it on my Mac, instead of a white page I get an error about Event.respondWith (Internal Error). Nog debug info whatsoever. But it’s super random happening, looks like a timing issue with registering or fetching.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).